# Html page in Servant -- how to combine REST API and static html pages?

Tags: haskell, servant

I have a simple hello world Servant application. I need to add some static or dynamic html pages to it. How can I do that? In the documentation it's not mentioned. Note I don't want to create a html layout in Haskell code, I want Haskell to show the html pages that's already created.

UPDATE:

How can I combine this:

```
type MyApi = "/" :> Raw

server :: Server MyApi
server = serveDirectory "static/" -- index.html, about.html
```

with what I have already:

```
  type API = 
    "api" :> "items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyData] :<|>
    "api" :> "items" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] MyData


  app :: Application
  app = serve api server

  api :: Proxy API
  api = Proxy

  server :: Server API
  server = getItems :<|> getItem

  startApp :: IO ()
  startApp =  run 1234 app
```

UPDATE2:

Working:

```
type API = 
    "api" :> "items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyData] :<|>
    "api" :> "items" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] MyData :<|>
    Raw
```

Not working, no response at all:

```
type API = 
    "api" :> "items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyData] :<|>
    "api" :> "items" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] MyData :<|>
    "/" :> Raw

-- or

type API = 
    "api" :> "items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyData] :<|>
    "api" :> "items" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] MyData :<|>
    "" :> Raw
```

I wonder why?

Comment: You can do `serveDirectory` if your static pages are already in correct structure.

Comment: @zakyggaps, updated.

Comment: Servant APIs will be matched in order, top to bottom. You can put it at the last line.

Comment: @zakyggaps, in the 1st "server" I have serveDirectory "static/" and in 2nd I have "getItems :<|> getItem" . How can I combine them?

Comment: You cannot do that: `:<|>` is right associative, if `"/" :> Raw` is the last case you have to define your API with all the three cases in it like `case1 :<|> case2 :<|> case3`.

Comment: @zakyggaps, what's the point for you of commenting here if you can write an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was searching for a duplicate but didn't find one. I will try organize an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to combine REST API and static html pages?

You may serve the directory containing your static website at root path by `serveDirectory`. It has to be the last case in your Servant API or other cases will never be matched.

```
type API = 
    "api" :> "items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyData] :<|>
    "api" :> "items" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] MyData :<|>
    Raw

api :: Proxy API 
api = Proxy

server :: Server API 
server = getItems
    :<|> getItem 
    :<|> serveDirectory "static/"
```

Also if any static page name crashes with your APIs it will be shadowed.

---

> why isn't it `"/" :> Raw`?

Looks like my browser cached some static pages. `"/" :> Raw` gives no response under `/index.html` after cleaned the cache.

a string literal in api will be encoded to legal uri parts first, therefore `"/"` will be `"%2F"` and your files are mapped to `/%2F/index.html` and so on.

---

> do you know how can I handle the root case?

To serve a response at root path, you may define a `Get` endpoint with no prefix:

```
type API = Get '[HTML] RawHtml
```

It can be anywhere in your API except the last line.

To serve a local file as html response you have to distinguish the file from other bytestrings, maybe wrap it in a newtype:

```
newtype RawHtml = RawHtml { unRaw :: BS.ByteString }

-- tell Servant how to render the newtype to html page, in this case simply unwrap it
instance MimeRender HTML RawHtml where
    mimeRender _ =  unRaw
```

and in your controller:

```
-- ...
:<|> fmap RawHtml (liftIO $ BS.readFile "your/file/path.html")
```

Or if the page has another address already, you can redirect users there:

```
-- ...
:<|> throwError err301 { errHeaders = [("Location", "index.html")] }
```

---

> it already returns index.html. Hm, why exactly index.html?

`serveDirectory` calls a wai application `staticApp` with a setting `defaultFileServerSettings`. In that setting users will be redirected to `index.htm` or `index.html` if something went wrong:

```
defaultFileServerSettings root = StaticSettings
    { ssLookupFile = fileSystemLookup (fmap Just . hashFile) root
    , ssMkRedirect = defaultMkRedirect
    , ssGetMimeType = return . defaultMimeLookup . fromPiece . fileName
    , ssMaxAge = NoMaxAge
    , ssListing = Just defaultListing
    , ssIndices = map unsafeToPiece ["index.html", "index.htm"]
    , ssRedirectToIndex = False
    , ssUseHash = False
    , ssAddTrailingSlash = False
    , ss404Handler = Nothing
    }
```

Comment: why isn't it `:<|> "" :>  Raw` or `:<|> "/" :> Raw`? why merely `:<|> Raw`?

Comment: Both `Raw` and `"/" :> Raw` will point to the root path. I chose the shorter.

Comment: actually `:<|> "" :> Raw` and `:<|> "/" :> Raw` aren't working. The server doesn't return anything, like it's not found. I wonder why?

Comment: @OskarK. I cannot reproduce that. `"/" :> Raw` and `Raw` have the same consequence as I tried.

Comment: do you know how can I handle the root case, that is, when I request "localhost:1234", how can I return the page "index.html"? Meaning, I want to return "index.html" for both "localhost:1234" and "localhost:1234/index.html"

Comment: actually, it already returns index.html. Hm, why exactly index.html?